# Retrieve dynamicaly the columns of a records

Tags: postgresql

my sql statement is built dynamicaly.
I have something like

`strSql := 'select name, tel, adress, activity_id as filtre_1, country_id as filtre_2, ... from ... where ...'`

I can have 1 to n filter, and filter_1 can be activity_id as country_id, the order in not important.

How can I retrieve the values of filter_1, filter_2 as I don't know how many the request send back?

Normaly to retrieve the values, I do :

```
FOR rowResult IN EXECUTE strSql LOOP
        name := rowResult.name
        tel := rowResult.tel
        adress := rowResult.adress
        filtre_1 := rowResult.filtre_1
        filtre_2 := rowResult.filtre_2
END LOOP;
```

As this cannot be done, I like to do something like

```
FOR rowResult IN EXECUTE strSql LOOP
        name := rowResult.name
        tel := rowResult.tel
        adress := rowResult.adress
        filtre_1 := rowResult("filtre_1")
        filtre_2 := rowResult("filtre_2")
END LOOP;
```

but `rowResult(stringfield)` do not exist.

Is somebody have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be there're more efficient ways, but you can access fields from anonymous records by converting it into array:

```
strSql := 'select name, activity_id, country_id from test where activity_id = 2 and country_id = 1';
for rowResult in execute strSql loop
    temp := string_to_array(trim(rowResult::text, '()'), ',');
    activity_id := temp[2];
    country_id := temp[3];
end loop;
```

see [**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d4a7b/35)

I think it's also possible to use [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) for that, but cannot test right now:

```
    temp := hstore(rowResult);
    activity_id := temp -> 'f2'
    country_id := temp -> 'f3'
```

Comment: The idea is good, but apparently I done something wrong because it's not working for me :

Comment: Here is the result of my temp variable :
NOTICE:  temp = {10,"","","","","","\"ABC 1.3.1.1\"","",33,42,"","",14,FILTRE,12,FILTRE,"",FILTRE,7,FILTRE}

When I try to read coloumn 11 I get this error message :
ERROR:  cannot subscript type text because it is not an array

Comment: how did you declare temp variable? you have to declare it as text[]

Comment: Yes it's possible with hstore but the name of the column is lost during the process if you use an older version than 9.2. You retrieve f1, f2, f3 instead of name, activity_id and country_id, which is not very easy to use

Comment: so do you think there's some other solution for this? I think it's possible if you define a type with activity_id, country_id fields

Comment: For my purpose, as my request will send back different fields (sometimes acivity_id will be present, other time not) I'm not sure we can find a better solution for postgre < 9.2. For the 9.2 the hstore is the solution : it's much easy to work with an associative array